# Efficiently analysing an Web Audio stream

Tags: html, web-audio-api

Assuming a X minutes audio stream, what is the fastest way to fully analyse it (i.e getting informations from a Web Audio AnalyserNode) without playing it (in no more than a few milliseconds / seconds) ?

Comment: You can't use the `AnalyserNode` without playing the audio, so you'd need to do your own FFT. There are a number of libraries available for that, like this one: https://github.com/JensNockert/fft.js

Comment: +1 @kevin fft is the way to go!